# Get parameters in http post request from postman

Tags: go, httprequest

I have a Go server but seems I can't get a list of POST (form) parameters in my server from the POST request

I send the request from postman when the option I selected in Body tab is `form-data` and the request looks like this:

```
POST /todo/323/item HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: ef4b5606-3079-fb02-824f-f58ae89ee6f3
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="aaa"

skhdfb
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

1213
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

I get null but when the option is `x-www-form-urlencoded` it works fine. What should I do?

this is how I try to get the value:

`fmt.Fprintln(w, req.FormValue("aaa"))`

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: We can't tell you how to fix your code if you don't show us your code.

Comment: @Flimzy the code is fairly simple I defined a root and inside my handler functions I wrote this and the code is OK when content-type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't simple. I said we need to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it's multipart you either have to do:

```
req.ParseMultipartForm(0)
fmt.Println(req.FormValue("aaa"))
```

or if you don't want to load the whole thing into memory, you could do:

```
form, err := req.MultipartReader()
for {
    part, err := form.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    if part.FormName() == "aaa" {
        buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
        buf.ReadFrom(part)
        fmt.Println(buf.String())
    } 
}
```